# Extract organization from a column with list of dictionaries using pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

My data frame has multiple columns like ID, Organizations, Date, Location, etc. I am trying to extract the "organization" values that are within the "Organizations" column. My desired output should be multiple organization's names in a new column, separated by a comma. For example:

| ID | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{organization=Glaxosmithkline, character_offset=10512}, {organization=Vulpes Fund, character_offset=13845}] |
| 2 | [{organization=Amazon, character_offset=14589}, {organization=Sinovac, character_offset=18923}] |

I want the output to be something like:

| ID | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Glaxosmithkline, Vulpes Fund |
| 2 | Amazon, Sinovac |

I tried the following code (getting output as NaN):

```
latin_combined['newOrg'] = latin_combined['organizations'].str[0].str['organization']
```

Edited:
 `df.head(5)['organizations'].to_dict()` gives me the following output:

```
{0: '[{organization= Vac, character_offset=14199}, {organization=Health, character_offset=1494}]',
 1: '[{organization=Store, character_offset=700}, {organization= Museum, character_offset=1711}]',
 2: '[{organization= Mart, character_offset=8232}, {organization= Rep, character_offset=5517}]',
 3: '[{organization= Lodge, character_offset=3881}, {organization= Hotel, character_offset=5947}]',
 4: '[{organization=Airport, character_offset=3881}, {organization=Landmark, character_offset=5947}]'}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: could you post the results of `df.head(5)['your interested column'].to_dict()` in your question

Comment: @onyambu I posted the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a string. You can use `regex` to extract the key, value pair separated by `=`, pivot as shown below:

```
(df['organizations'].str.extractall('([^{=,]+)= *([^=,}]+)') 
  .rename({0:'key', 1:'value'}, axis = 1).reset_index()
  .groupby(['level_0', 'key'])['value'].agg(', '.join).unstack())

key      character_offset       organization
level_0                                     
0             14199, 1494        Vac, Health
1               700, 1711      Store, Museum
2              8232, 5517          Mart, Rep
3              3881, 5947       Lodge, Hotel
4              3881, 5947  Airport, Landmark
```

---

The data

```
d = {0: '[{organization= Vac, character_offset=14199}, {organization=Health, character_offset=1494}]',
 1: '[{organization=Store, character_offset=700}, {organization= Museum, character_offset=1711}]',
 2: '[{organization= Mart, character_offset=8232}, {organization= Rep, character_offset=5517}]',
 3: '[{organization= Lodge, character_offset=3881}, {organization= Hotel, character_offset=5947}]',
 4: '[{organization=Airport, character_offset=3881}, {organization=Landmark, character_offset=5947}]'}

df = pd.Series(d).to_frame('organizations')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
latin_combined['newOrg'] = latin_combined['organizations'].apply(lambda x : x.split(',')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension with apply:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[[{'organization':'Glaxosmithkline', 'character_offset':10512}, {'organization':'Vulpes Life Sciences Fund', 'character_offset':13845}]]], columns=['newOrg'])
df['Organizations'] = df['newOrg'].apply(lambda x: [i['organization'] for i in x])
```

output:

|  | newOrg | Organizations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'organization': 'Glaxosmithkline', 'character_offset': 10512}, {'organization': 'Vulpes Life Sciences Fund', 'character_offset': 13845}] | ['Glaxosmithkline', 'Vulpes Life Sciences Fund'] |

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Updated following your recent dataframe update:

```
data = {'Organizations': ['[{organization= Vac, character_offset=14199}, {organization=Health, character_offset=1494}]',
        '[{organization=Store, character_offset=700}, {organization= Museum, character_offset=1711}]',
        '[{organization= Mart, character_offset=8232}, {organization= Rep, character_offset=5517}]',
        '[{organization= Lodge, character_offset=3881}, {organization= Hotel, character_offset=5947}]',
        '[{organization=Airport, character_offset=3881}, {organization=Landmark, character_offset=5947}]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

| index | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{organization= Vac, character_offset=14199}, {organization=Health, character_offset=1494}] |
| 1 | [{organization=Store, character_offset=700}, {organization= Museum, character_offset=1711}] |
| 2 | [{organization= Mart, character_offset=8232}, {organization= Rep, character_offset=5517}] |
| 3 | [{organization= Lodge, character_offset=3881}, {organization= Hotel, character_offset=5947}] |
| 4 | [{organization=Airport, character_offset=3881}, {organization=Landmark, character_offset=5947}] |

**2.** Use `''.join()` + `regex` with `.apply()` on the column you want:

```
import re
df.Organizations = df.Organizations.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(re.findall(r'{[^=]+=\s*([^=,}]+)', x)))
df
```

**3.** Result:

| index | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Vac, Health |
| 1 | Store, Museum |
| 2 | Mart, Rep |
| 3 | Lodge, Hotel |
| 4 | Airport, Landmark |

In my own opinion, you should try to better scrap and/or clean your data before putting them into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df['organizations'].str.extractall(r"organization= *(\w+)") \
    .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join).rename(columns={0:'Organizations'})

       Organizations
0        Vac, Health
1      Store, Museum
2          Mart, Rep
3       Lodge, Hotel
4  Airport, Landmark
```